# Disabling radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable these radio buttons when a the loadActive link is clicked but for some reason it only disables the first in the order and then skips the rest.

```
<form id="chatTickets" method="post" action="/admin/index.cfm/">
    <input id="ticketID1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="myvalue1" name="ticketID"/>
    <input id="ticketID2" type="radio" checked="checked" value="myvalue2" name="ticketID"/>
</form>
<a href="#" title="Load ActiveChat" id="loadActive">Load Active</a>
```

And Here is the jquery i'm using:

```
jQuery("#loadActive").click(function() {
    //I have other code in here that runs before this function call
    writeData();
});
function writeData() {
    jQuery("input[name='ticketID']").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using firebug, use the selector to get an array of elements and see how many are in the array?

Comment: everything you have there works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah it works in my sandbox as well, although this is coming from a much larger file I think something else is making it not work. Using classes, selecting it differently still ONLY disables the first radio and not the rest. But in sandbox it works perfectly ugh

Comment: then it has to be something other than what you are showing us.

Answer (score 63):

Remove your "each" and just use:

```
$('input[name=ticketID]').attr("disabled",true);
```

That simple. It works

Answer (score 53):

I've refactored your code a bit, this should work:

```
jQuery("#loadActive").click(writeData);

function writeData() {
    jQuery("#chatTickets input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
}
```

If there are more than two radio buttons on your form, you'll have to modify the selector, for example, you can use the [starts with attribute filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) to pick out the radios whose ID starts with `ticketID`:

```
function writeData() {
    jQuery("#chatTickets input[id^=ticketID]:radio").attr('disabled',true);
}
```

Comment: that'll disable every radio button in that form. in his question there might only be two, but there are likely going to be more.

Comment: @geowa4 - true, I assumed those were the only radios on his form. In any case, I've edited to be a bit more useful.

Comment: +1 for removing the useless `.each()`; `.attr()` will apply to all selected elements anyway.

Comment: This code is quite out dated. Use the method by KCOtzen below.

Answer (score 10):

just use jQuery `prop`

```
 $(".radio-button").prop("disabled", false);
 $(".radio-button").prop("disabled", true); // disable
```

Answer (score 9):

First, the valid syntax is

```
jQuery("input[name=ticketID]")
```

second, have you tried:

```
jQuery(":radio")
```

instead?

third, 
why not assign a class to all the radio buttons, and select them by class?

Comment: Actually "input[name='ticketID']" is valid syntax, the single quotes are just not necessary.

Comment: why not just use the name? and select them by that? it should work fine; i've done it a million times.

Comment: I agree with mkoryak: "assign a class to all the radio buttons, and select them by class"

Comment: then you have to maintain both classnames and names when names suffice

Comment: jQuery selector speeds - classes are faster than attributes

Comment: i think we should solve his problem before making optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

I just built a sandbox environment with your code and it worked for me. Here is what I used:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="chatTickets" method="post" action="/admin/index.cfm/">
      <input id="ticketID1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="myvalue1" name="ticketID"/>
      <input id="ticketID2" type="radio" checked="checked" value="myvalue2" name="ticketID"/>
    </form>
    <a href="#" title="Load ActiveChat" id="loadActive">Load Active</a>

    <script>
      jQuery("#loadActive").click(function() {
        //I have other code in here that runs before this function call
        writeData();
      });
      function writeData() {
        jQuery("input[name='ticketID']").each(function(i) {
            jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tested in FF3.5, moving to IE8 now. And it works fine in IE8 too. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

code:

```
function writeData() {
    jQuery("#chatTickets input:radio[id^=ticketID]:first").attr('disabled', true);
    return false;
}
```

See also: [Selector/radio](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/radio), [Selector/attributeStartsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue), [Selector/first](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first)

Comment: pretty sure this is the exact opposite of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code.

```
var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="ticketID1" value="myvalue1">');
if('some condition'){
    $(radioBtn).attr('disabled', true); // Disable the radio button.
    $('.span_class').css('opacity', '.2'); // Set opacity to .2 to mute the text in front of the radio button.
}else{
    $(radioBtn).attr('disabled', false);
    $('.span_class').css('opacity', '1');
}
```