# Unable to select all radio buttons in first three rows of a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which I have in every row I have around 11 radio boxes and few other attributes also.
I want to make radio buttons of first 3 rows non editable and using below code for same. Please suggest why it is not working.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr:lt(2) input[type=radio]').prop('readOnly',true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling radio buttons with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406544/disabling-radio-buttons-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use prop `disabled` as `true`:

```
$('tr:lt(2) input[type=radio]').prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: read-only doesn't work in radio buttons. see this answer for work around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953017/why-cant-radio-buttons-be-readonly

Answer (score 0):

None of the above code is working, pls see the sample html below and suggest.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('tr:lt(3)').find('input[type=radio]').prop('readonly',true);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border='1'>

<tr>
<td>Test1</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test2</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test3</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test4</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test5</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test6</td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
<td><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```