# How do disable bootstrap radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to disable choosing bootstrap radio button.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-set-or-raise">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" val="option1" >Radio 1 

</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-set-or-raise">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" val="option2" >Radio 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" >Radio 3
</label>
```

Here is the jquery to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-group :input").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

But I still see that one can click it, and I retrieve as a checked element!

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deligeli/3xqxqmyw/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code is working fine disabled attribute is there on input radio but there is still click working on label as input radio in inside the label.

pass disabled attribute to label also

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".btn-group label").attr("disabled", true);
   $(".btn-group :input").attr("disabled", true);
 });

 function checkSelected() {
   if ($("input[name=options]:checked").length > 0)
     console.log("one is selected!");
   else
     console.log("none are selected!");
 }
```

```css
label[disabled]{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-set-or-raise">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" val="option1">Radio 1

  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-set-or-raise">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" val="option2">Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3">Radio 3
  </label>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="checkSelected()" value="Check Selected" />
```

**Note** : This only prevents it to show you its click event but if you need to prevent it completely from click pass `pointer-events:none` to disabled label in css

Comment: it's not working. because if the user clicks, it may not disable it as clicked, but the checkSelected will display that the element is clicked!

Comment: Thanks. why would anyone ever want to enable the event if the label is disabled? shouldn't it be out of the box solution?

Comment: disabled attribute is just setting cursor to not allowed or preventing button to execute something but yes if it is click and you check weather it is click or not it will show the actual thing. `pointer-events:none` will stop clicking.

Comment: I accepted it now that it works.  I still think that disabling wouldn't let also setting the status to checked..

Comment: What if the user deselects the bootstrap button? I also need to deselect the checkbox - how can I do it? currently if the user deselects the label, the checkbox is still selected

Answer (score 3):

I hope this one help you

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
    </script>
```

Comment: the problem is that the element is STILL marked as checked if the user clicks on it!

Comment: $("input:radio").attr("checked", false); or $("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");

Comment: it didn't help - try it in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

you can use html attribute like this :

```html
<input type="radio" disabled="disabled">
```

or you can use jquery by get id selector:

```js
$("#option1").attr('disabled',true);
```

---

see [Disabling radio buttons with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406544/disabling-radio-buttons-with-jquery)

Comment: it's not working. because if the user clicks, it may not disable it as clicked, but the checkSelected will display that the element is clicked!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `disabled` class to label which is parent of radio button:

```
$(".btn-group label").addClass("disabled");
```

Here us the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpu15Ly4/)

Comment: It's not working. because if the user clicks, it may not disable it as clicked, but the checkSelected will display that the element is clicked!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `disabled` class to the label you like. Here is an example in your code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-set-or-raise">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" val="option1" >Radio 1 

</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary btn-set-or-raise">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" val="option2" disabled="disabled">Radio 2
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" >Radio 3
</label>
```

I disabled the second radio option